# Correct way to copy text from a file opened in Vim in one terminal into another opened file using VIM in another terminal?

Tags: centos, vim

I was able to do this the other day but now it does not want to work. Basically, to copy text from a file that I opened using VIM from one terminal into another file opened in a separate terminal, I am suppose to use +y to yank the text and use +p to be able to paste between terminals.

Now today, it does not want to work so maybe I am remembering how to do it wrong.

I am pressing "shift", "+",and "y" keys at the same time and I see the terminal saying it has been "yanked".

Now I go to the other file currently opened in another terminal and try to paste by pressing the "shift","+", and "p" keys to execute the +p command but I'm not getting the right text pasted into my file. I believe I'm still pasting the previous text that I yanked from the same file itself.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I think you're not remembering the full commands, you seem to be missing a `"` at the start.

It's actually `"+y` to yank and `"+p` to put. `"+` is a reference to the clipboard register.

To copy: <kbd>"</kbd><kbd>+</kbd><kbd>y</kbd>

To paste: <kbd>"</kbd><kbd>+</kbd><kbd>p</kbd>

See [`:help "+`](https://vimhelp.org/gui_x11.txt.html#quoteplus) for a reference on the clipboard register.